# Sharepoint 2013 Web Crawler

Tags: performance, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-crawler, sharepoint-2013

My group has been using Sharepoint 2010 to crawl a large number of external sites.

The Sharepoint web crawler did not provide sufficient configurability, so we've been using the FAST web crawler to run our crawls.

However, in Sharepoint 2013, it looks like the FAST web crawler has been deprecated/merged with the Sharepoint web crawler.

I can't find significant documentation on how to configure the 2013 Web Crawler component.  Is it more powerful than the Sharepoint crawler in 2010?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft TechNet on SP 2013 Crawler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742.aspx)